# Android floating action button hidden behind of bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout

New to android programming & struggling with right now. I'm using android studio's default "Navigation Drawer Activity".  On top of that, I've added a Bottom Bar from `https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar`. But, after adding that my FAB has hidden behind the Bottom Bar.

Here is the Scrrenshot -

[image]

I know it's some kind of style issue. I tried to give bottomMargin for FAB. But, it's not working.

Here is my code -

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.bhramaan.android.bhramaan.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/BhramaanTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/BhramaanTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_behavior="shy"
        android:background="@color/bottomBar"
        app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/white"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Need Some Guidance to solve this.

Comment: add this line to the android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton in Xml   android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"

Comment: Check my answer below let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: @Nithinlal LOLZ have you tried with giving this `add this line to the android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton in Xml android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"` just try it with above layout. is it holding this property or not !!!!!!!!!.

Comment: Right answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43132366/8781554

Comment: Add FloatingActionButton code block below BottomBar code block in xml.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Change your `xml` as this. Add some more properties to your `Floating Action Button`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: static values for setting the margin from the bottom is not correct

Comment: @Nithinlal What he need in OP is hiding `FAB` beside `Bottom Bar` using this `margin_bottom` will not hide this. The answer is making sense related to question. no need to down vote this for no major reason. Static values doesn't matter here for `margins` because `FAB` will be always remains at bottom right.

Comment: Hey, It worked. I've just one concern that as it has ```android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"``` If we hide the bottom bar then it's still in it's place. Can't we do something where it'll relatively use margin from Bottom bar. So, when bottom bar will get hide FAB will automatically come down.

Comment: I down voted because u r not using android proper constraints method

Comment: @Nithinlal I said you just down voted for no major reason.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart u can't change the position dynamically by using this.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart For that you may be need to do dynamically.May be you need to do it `programmatically`. by using `xml` you can only doing by this way. Appreciate and upvote my answer if it helped you thanks :).

Comment: @jaydroider u got the reason why I am down vote if u write it correctly it will work for all scenario but it fail now for another scenario

Comment: Hey Guys, have u seen google plus app. How it's managing bottom bar with FAB. on scroll down both bottom bar & fab gets hide & on scroll up both again comes up .I want to do something like that.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=floating check this library select according to ur requirement

Comment: @mi6crazyheart Try it `programmatically` to maintain that and if you face any issue in that then post here. because nobody will right code for that :).I have written answer making sense to OP.

Answer (score 4):

Add app:elevation="@dimen/text_margin" like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:elevation="@dimen/text_margin" /><!--adding this line should resolve your problem-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that works for our use case. Basically we wanted to hide bottom navigation view and the fab that belongs to it whenever the user scrolls in the screen.

For that purpose we have decided to use the `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"` that comes out of the box for `BottomNavigationView`. All that is left is to anchor the fab to the `BottomNavigationView` and use the same `layout_behavior` on fab, too.

Here is an example of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/inc_app_bar"/>

    <fragment
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_nav_graph"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/main_bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@style/Theme.BottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/main_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/main_bottom_nav_view"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_end"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24px"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Other than that you can define your own layout_behavior for fab as explained in [GitHub: BlogPosts / android-coordinatorlayout-scrolling-hide-fab-behavior.md](https://github.com/newfivefour/BlogPosts/blob/master/android-coordinatorlayout-scrolling-hide-fab-behavior.md)  too.

I hope that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In advance I let other know this solution fits to my needs. I don't need fancy animations(which is ok, but not for my project requirements). What I did is to wrap the main content(FrameLayout), the FAB and the BottomNavigationView inside a RelativeLayout. Again, I think this could be done in a better way, so i'm open to suggestions.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/admin_appbar_layout"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:elevation="4dp">

        <!-- The toolbar -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/admin_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/customActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/customActionBar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/H2_bold"
                    android:text="@string/activity_admin_name"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_new_item"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_dimen"
            tools:elevation="2dp"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/black"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/admin_bottom_navigation_items"
            tools:elevation="2dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I know the question may seems old, but hope this helps to someone else.

Comment: This answer is correct only if we don't use shy behavior (bottom bar hide when scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

Its just margin issue. Just try to implement this code in your `coordinatorLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            style="@style/floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_plus" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And use this style in your style.xml file.

```
<style name="floating_action_button">
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">16dp</item>

</style>
```

We're just doubling the margin. First BottomNavigationView, and Second the default margin of FAB.

Answer (score 0):

simply add.

```
app:elevation="10dp"
```

it worked for me.