# FloatingActionButton with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I cant position my FAB. It should be bottom right, but on top of the BottonNavigationView.

1) Can i achieve this without RelativeLayout inside coordinateLayout?

2) Show me how

3) Should i use FrameLayout as a container for fragments?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_electricity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_electro" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: result]

Comment: https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/issues/38

Comment: Question repeated. Look at this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61584002/13436292

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A quick search to `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` tells us the following thing.

```java
@Override
public void onAttachedToLayoutParams(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp) {
    if (lp.dodgeInsetEdges == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY) {
        // If the developer hasn't set dodgeInsetEdges, lets set it to BOTTOM so that
        // we dodge any Snackbars
        lp.dodgeInsetEdges = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    }
}
```

Since `BottomNavigationView` also resides at the bottom of the layout. Add following element to your `BottomNavigationView` and `CoordinatorLayout` will handle the inset and dodging for you automatically.

```xml
app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
```

Comment: I had to ensure my bottom bar was in the same xml as the FAB (rather than some included child layout)

Comment: @DanielWilson To be exact, both `BottomNavigationView` and `FloatingActionButton` have to be the direct descendant (child) of `CoordinatorLayout` for this to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you stick it in a linear layout and move the bottom nav outside of the coordinator view, it will be below it on the screen.
2. You could do it this way, but I prefer using an empty fragment container which I put in the hosting activity, and then place the fragment inside of it in code.

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/appbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
          app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


   </FrameLayout>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab_electricity"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_electro"/>



   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom">

   </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640518/bottomnavigationview-with-floatingactionbutton-inside-coordinatorlayout-dont-mat