# Android FloatingActionButton with fragment and bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm creating an android app with the following structure:

- The main activity has a bottom navigation bar switching between 3 different fragments
- 2 of the fragments are going to display lists of items, with a floating action button (FAB) to add new items
- The 3rd fragment is going to show something different, that doesn't need a FAB.

Based on this, it seems like the FAB should "belong" to the list fragments, and not the main activity.

I am currently have the problem that the FAB hides itself behind the bottom navigation bar, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128947/floatingactionbutton-with-bottomnavigationview). There is a nice solution there, but it depends on the the FAB being in the same layout as the bottom navigation bar.

Is there a way to get the FAB to not hide itself behind the bottom navigation, without moving the FAB up to the main activity (which breaks the modularity of the fragments)?

---

My activity layout is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

where the "fragment container" is replaced by the selected fragment as below:

```java
    TodoListFragment fragment = new TodoListFragment();

    //if we were started with an intent, pass on any special arguments
    fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .commit();
```

and finally the fragment has layout as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="..."
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".TodoListFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_todolist_item" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is with your constraints. You are setting FrameLayout's height to match parent. Try this -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation"/>
```

Comment: This. It's tricky to figure this out because when you use Android Studio's project creation wizard and choose to start as a BottomNavigation app the pre-configured activity layout Google gives you has the fragment view's height set to `match_parent` instead of `0dp`.